# How to specify a concrete instance to use in a constructor in StructureMap

Tags: c#, structuremap

I am trying to register the class `DialogService` in StructureMap and trying to define the concrete instances that StructureMap should use for the construction of the corresponding singleton object.

I have gotten it to work like this:

```
this.For<DialogService>()
    .Use<DialogService>()
    .Ctor<IDialogCoordinator>("dialogCoordinator").Is(new DialogCoordinator())
    .Ctor<ViewModelBase>("parentViewModel").Is(new MainWindowViewModel(new MainViewModel()))
    .Singleton();
```

However instead of using `new MainViewModel()` and `new MainWindowViewModel` I would like to instruct StructureMap to use the corresponding registered Singletons instead, which I have registered like this:

```
this.For<MainWindowViewModel>().Use<MainWindowViewModel>().Singleton();
this.For<MainViewModel>().Use<MainViewModel>().Singleton();
```

How do I achieve this?

For completeness here is the constructor of `DialogService`:

```
DialogService(IDialogCoordinator dialogCoordinator, ViewModelBase parentViewModel)
```

Comment: Why are you doing `new DialogCoordinator()` when that is the job of the DI framework?

Comment: Good point. I have `this.For<IDialogCoordinator>().Use<DialogCoordinator>().Singleton();` in my registry, but that leaves me with the problem, that I need to somehow define the second argument of the constructor. I guess I could do `this.For<ViewModelBase>().Use<MainWindowViewModel>().Singleton();`, but registering against a base-class does not seem clean to me.

Comment: You could do that, or use named registration

Comment: And how would I do it using named registration? I am still very new to the usage of StructureMap....

Comment: I would read this part of the [documentation](http://structuremap.github.io/registration/policies/) this is extremely powerful stuff, and will sort out half your issues at least

Comment: I strongly recommend reading through the documentation, and trying out the examples.

Comment: @CallumLinington Thanks for the pointer to the documentation. Will read up and then post my solution.